# What is wrong with this concatenation function?

Tags: c

```
char* StrCat(char* dest, char* source)
{
    char* retVal = dest;

    while(*dest)
        dest++;

    while(*dest++ = *source++) ;

    return retVal;
}

int main()
{
    char* a = "One";
    char* b = "Two";

    char* x = StrCat(a, b);

    printf("%s\n", x);

    return 0;
}
```

The program crashes the first time when copying from source to destination, second while loop. (`Access violation` error)

Comment: First tell me what is right with this concatenation function (that you think) ?

Comment: Why don't you use `strcpy` function from `string.h` ?

Comment: It looks like he's learning C.  It's a good thing to try re-implementing strcat manually without any help of libc.

Comment: Yeah, trying to learn more about pointers

Comment: One thing about C-style strings/charArrays is that you cannot just magically extend them, eg. by seeking to the end and adding more chars from another string.  It's UB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Content of variables a and b (character strings "One" and "Two") are stored in read-only segments, content is protected, you cannot overwrite its data.

Plus, StrCat() function has not much logic.

You'd need to use a global *char* array, or a *char* array that you pass to the function that has a limited size and make sure you don't go beyond its buffer size during the copy, otherwise you will end up with a stack overflow.

Another solution would be to allocate memory dynamically using *malloc*, this memory should be freed when you don't need it anymore.

Rethink how you would write such a function to correct it, but first fix this memory issue.

Comment: a and b aren't stored in read-only segments. What they point to is.

Comment: Totally true - Thanks for the comment Tom.

Comment: It won't be stack overflow, it will be UB.